# How to configure sumo-launchd.py to get Lanearea Detectors output？

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am learning **sumo** and **Veins**, using the **F2MD framework** for simulation, but I have encountered some problems. I am trying to get **Lanearea Detectors output** with sumo, when I can use the command:"sumo-gui -a lust.add.xml"(which already set Lanearea Detectors additional) ,I can get the output file like:xxx.output.xml. But when i use sumo-launchd.py to start the same simulation,it don't have any output file , This confuses me, hope someone can help me, thank！

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the sumo configuration which is running and add the line

```
<additional-files value="lust.add.xml"/>
```

or add the file to the list if the entry is already present.

Comment: Thanks for your help! and I have alreadly added it to the .sumocfg file, but it seems that when running the simulation through the sumolaunchd.py file provided in the F2MD framework, the corresponding file is not output, instead of using sumolaunchd.py, directly pass: "sumo-gui due.actuated.sumocfg" command, I can get the output I want，This is the core of the problem I meet. There are two different ways to start the sumo simulation, but only one has an output file. Looking forward to your help，Thanks again!

Comment: Can you maybe do something like `ps -ef` while the process is running to find out which configuration it is actually using?